# pass multiple ids through ajax to get the results from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to pass multiple values through ajax request like

```
var ids = 10 ,15,30;
```

is it possible to do this if not how do i pass the ids in the request?

```
 $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: $('#baseurl').val()+"/ajax_requests/testing.php",
                 data:{row :ids,action:"get_values"},
                 async :false,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function(result){
                        if(result)
                        {
                            alert("success")
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Once i pass these values how do i go about in fetching the results in test.php

Comment: Use an array: `var ids = [10, 15, 30]`

Comment: _"Once i pass these values how do i go about in fetching the results in test.php"_ The same way you sent a 'normal form', use `$_POST['varname']`

Comment: Moreover, since you're using `jQuery` you have the function [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) which may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are a lot of possibilities how to send several values. The solution depends only on how you would like to parse them in PHP. Here are some possibilities that gets on my mind:

1. Just make a string with comma-separated values. Like:

   var ids = "10,15,30";
   After that in PHP you will have to split these values by ",".
2. You can make JSON object and pass it. In PHP you will have to parse JSON object.
3. You can pass just like an array and treat it like an array in PHP.
   These are the easiest possibilities I see.

Note: there's very good function in jQuery that allows to pack easily all needed information from the page: [.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this data as string

```
data:{row :"10,15,30",action:"get_values"},
```

or as array

```
data:{row[]:10, row[]:15, row[]:30,action:"get_values"},
```

depending what your php expect